# Format PrimeFaces Slider InputText

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

I have a PrimeFaces slider with an associated inputText. Everything is working fine, except I can´t find a way of formatting the inputText value. I want the inputText to show and get values in currency format.

What I've tried so far:

- Changing the `p:inputText` with a `pe:inputNumber` component: causes an exception because the value can't be set (slider simply doesn´t work with inputNumber);
- Setting the `p:slider` target to a `h:inputHidden` component with the same value than `p:inputText` (with a `f:convertNumber` attached to): works when changing values through slider, but when using inputText to change the value slider doesn´t update (throws an UpdateModelException behind the scenes);

**Update: it was found later that the second option exception is thrown because `f:convertNumber` expects a number type bean property, not an integer one. Both solutions shown below work around this issue.**

Is there a simple way of doing this without using jQuery?

Thanks!

Filipe

Comment: I think that the right way is your third point. Do you use the same bean property for both components?

Comment: Only the inputText requires a bean property, the slider only requires an inputText that it will write data to AFAIK.

Comment: Do you need an `inputText`? You can achieve this using `inputHidden` and `display` attribute of `slider`

Comment: @giaffa86 that´s the second option I tried. I need an inputText where the user can also type the value, so it's not a valid option.

Comment: Yes but if you don't need strictly an `InputText` you can achieve this using an `outputText` as shown in Primefaces Showcase.

Comment: @giaffa86 yes! And actually I did it while testing. The thing is: I really need an inputText - and I still believe there must be a way to format it! :)

Comment: I tried a couple of solutions but none work as you wish. Currently the only thing that partially works is `onSlideEnd` event but this implies that you are not able to see live update when slide is moving.

Comment: @giaffa86 Tks for your interest. Could you post what you got using onSlideEnd? I´m using onSlideEnd, but I´m not able to get slider + formattedInputText in both directions with it too. Updating while moving is not a requirement. Actually as each slider end causes some complex filtering to be triggered, it's not even desirable. Tks again!

Comment: I posted it as answer. In this way you can couple whatever component you want to slider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are 2 ways of solving this problem:

1. Creating a custom converter (drafted by @giaffa86 in his solution);
2. Enabling Number getters and setters to the int property and using them with inputText (what's simpler, IMO).

The code below shows how to implement the second option.

**TestView.java**

```
@ManagedBean(name="testView")
@ViewScoped
public class TestView {

    private int realValue = 500;

    public int getValueAsInt() {
        return this.realValue;
    }

    public Number getValueAsNumber() {
        return (Number)realValue;
    }

    public void setValueAsInt(int value) {
        this.realValue = value;
    }

    public void setValueAsNumber(Number value) {
        this.realValue = value.intValue();
    }

    public void onSlideEnd(SlideEndEvent event) {
        this.realValue = event.getValue();
    }
}
```

**view.xhtml**

```
    <p:inputText id="input" value="#{testView.valueAsNumber}">
        <p:ajax update="slider" />
        <f:convertNumber currencySymbol="$" type="currency"
            integerOnly="true" />
    </p:inputText>

    <h:inputHidden id="hidden" value="#{testView.valueAsInt}" />
    <p:slider id="slider" for="hidden" minValue="0" maxValue="1000" step="10">
        <p:ajax event="slideEnd" listener="#{testView.onSlideEnd}" update="input" />                    
    </p:slider>
```

This solution, as the first option, also loses live update, but that's no problem in my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Below I posted minimal requirements to obtain a custom `inputText` but you lost live update on it.

**SliderView.java**

```
private int number1 = 0;
private String number2 = String.valueOf(number1);

public int getNumber1() {
return number1;
}

public void setNumber1(int number1) {
this.number1 = number1;
}



public String getNumber2() {
return number2;
}

public void setNumber2(String number2) {
this.number2 = number2;
}

public void converToInt() {
log.debug(number2);
//TODO should be improved
this.number1 = Integer.parseInt(number2);
}

public void onSlideEnd(SlideEndEvent event) {
log.debug("current number: " + event.getValue());
this.number1 = event.getValue();
this.number2 = String.valueOf(event.getValue());

}
```

**slider.xhtml**

```
<h:form id="bcr_form_2" styleClass="form">
    <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
        <p:inputMask id="output" value="#{sliderView.number2}">
            <p:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{sliderView.converToInt}" update="@form:txt @form:slider" />
            <f:converter converterId="CurrencyConverter" />
            <pe:keyFilter regEx="/[0-9_]/i" />
        </p:inputMask>
        <h:inputHidden id="txt" value="#{sliderView.number1}" />
        <p:slider id="slider" for="txt" style="width: 200px">
            <p:ajax event="slideEnd" listener="#{sliderView.onSlideEnd}" update="@form:output" />
        </p:slider>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

**CurrencyConverter.java**

```
@FacesConverter("CurrencyConverter")
public class CurrencyConverter implements Converter {
  @Override
  public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    return value.replace('€', ' ').trim();
  }

  @Override
  public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    return value.toString() + "€";
  }
}
```

Glad to be helpful.

Comment: I´ll give it a try later and let you know. I need full format, not only the currency symbol, but I will try using a converter and see if with the hidden field it works. input + converter + slider w/out inputHidden wasn's working very well. Tks!

Comment: I was implementing it right now but there's a problem with this implementation: when changing the slider value the inputText will be updated, but the contraty isn´t true, right? I mean, if I update the value directly in the inputText, the slider will not update itself (position and value), as they are not linked. So, unfortunately it´s not an acceptable solution.

Comment: I mande some more tests with f:convertNumber h:inputText and p:slider. Looks like there is a problem as convertNumber works with number or float and slider with integers only, so I get an UpdateModelException when working with f:convertNumber. Maybe a custom converter can do the trick, I´ll take a look deeper later.

Comment: You got reason about update of slider from inputText. I updated my solution.

Comment: a big thank you for all your help. I posted another solution that I think that is simpler and avoids having to deal with differente locale formats inside the converter, so I think it would be of greater help to be marked as answer. Is it ok for you? Again, thank you very much,

Comment: No problem. You surely lose more time than me. Glad to be helpful.